Issue with OAuth authentication for Microsoft personal account
I am encountering issues while attempting OAuth authentication for my Microsoft account. Here's the situation:
I have successfully implemented OAuth authentication for Office 365 (O365) accounts, and users within our organization, registered under our O365 account, can obtain tokens and access IMAP without any problems.
However, when I try to use the O365 tenant, client ID, and secret for my personal Outlook account (xyz@outlook.com), I can successfully obtain tokens, but encounter an error when trying to access IMAP. The error message received is as follows:

The IMAP server replied to the 'NAMESPACE' command with a 'BAD' response: User is authenticated but not connected.

To address this issue, I registered an application under my personal account and used the corresponding tenant, client ID, and secret for OAuth access. However, this resulted in the following error:

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50034: The user account {EUII Hidden} does not exist in the 351a6e48-4835-4cd2-bb80-18a747e85690 directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory. Trace ID: 433da59c-4d33-415f-9df8-2c5e8a216201 Correlation ID: 4deb0eac-c168-4f76-8fa4-f6aabd7f9cfd Timestamp: 2024-04-16 03:58:24Z","error_codes":[50034],"timestamp":"2024-04-16 03:58:24Z","trace_id":"433da59c-4d33-415f-9df8-2c5e8a216201","correlation_id":"4deb0eac-c168-4f76-8fa4-f6aabd7f9cfd","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50034"}
It appears that the user account specified does not exist in the associated directory

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I want to auth successfully with outlook personal account and also want to access imap.
So OAuth is possible on Outlook personal account or not, if possible then please explain me what was the issue in my case

The error "AADSTS50034: The user account XXX does not exist in the XXX directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory" usually occurs if the user account you are trying to sign is personal account and you are not making use of common endpoint to authorize.
Hence to resolve the error, you need to create the Microsoft Entra ID application by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)":

To authorize the Microsoft personal account users, you need to make use of common endpoint:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=515b2299-61a7-4ee5-b6da-19085fdef6e4
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
&state=12345



Now, I generated access token successfully by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret



Thanks for response @Rukmini, but what actually issue i'm facing when i try to connect imap using retrieved accesstoken, it's throwing error like Imapclient is not connected
I have followed same stuff which you have recommended to me

Did you decode the token?
